# SQLite Empty value vs NULL value

Tags: sqlite

I created a table named M_PRODUCT which has 3 fields

```
ID : INTEGER, Primary key, NOT NULL
Name: TEXT
Price: INTEGER
```

I insert 3 records into newly created table

```
ID | Name | Price
1  | A    | NULL
2  | B    | 300
3  | C    | <blank>
```

When I tried to execute the following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM M_PRODUCT WHERE M_PRODUCT.PRICE > 200
```

I got 2 records

```
ID | Name | Price
2  | B    | 300
3  | C    | <blank>
```

It seems that NULL equals to 0 so the record with name A doesn't satisfy the condition.

But I don't understand why the row with blank price can get into the returned result.

Does blank get converted to special value?

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparison_expressions) to see how values of different types are ordered.

Comment: What was the query for inserting those rows? I don't think I ever saw `<blank>` before, I wonder how it got there.

Comment: Please note that `NULL` is NOT equals to 0. `NULL` is not equal to anything, not even itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, the rules for [comparing values](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparison_expressions) say:

> A value with storage class NULL is considered less than any other value (including another value with storage class NULL).
>
> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value

which implies that a TEXT or BLOB value is greater than any INTEGER or REAL. So when you test `M_PRODUCT.PRICE > 200`, the TEXT `<blank>` is greater than the INTEGER `200` and that row thus matches. And your `NULL` value is of course less than anything else, so it doesn't match.